# Java TCP with msg Identifier, how to handle

Tags: java, tcp

I was looking at some TCP tutorials but some things i do not understand.
Lets say i had data received from client to server represented as "01100,100" where 2 first chars "01" = type identifier and rest "100,100" = Y, X needed store to server.
Now server can have lots of type numbers as they can be from "00" to "99"

I know that one way to do reaction can be HashMap with Lambda (or similar reflection or what ever) and call specific method that handle "01" based on received identifier.

```
    protocols = new HashMap<>();
    protocols.put("01", () -> Position(aMsg));

private void Position(String msg) {
    systemLog(" -> [dataRecived] "+msg);
}
```

But i do not think that is a good way to go specifically because parametar need to be passed.

What is the best (fastest) practice to handle them for calling specific method based on that data? Should Switch be fast enough. Or something else to handle them from "00" to "99"?

Comment: I don't think you have anywhere nearly enough understanding about anything to do socket programming. Although I am intrigued about `HashMap` with [Lambada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambada).

Comment: Oh, edited that, newer the less that is why a posted a question, if i knew i would not ask it.

Comment: But you don't seem to have **any** understanding about what you're doing. You need the kind of help that weeks of careful studying can provide, not the kind of help you can give with a simple SO answer.

Comment: I understand your concern, problem is that most tutorials online are to "how to create server client" "how to send and receive data", trying to search on how to handle data or how to construct them is lacking or at least i'm searching for wrong things.I do not need " kind of help that weeks of careful studying can provide", i need push in a right direction so that i can learn even if it consume "weeks of careful studying"

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you read received data from *InputStream*. For each type identifier function like

```
private void position(InputStream stream) {
    int x = // read x from InputStream
    int y = // read y from InputStream
    systemLog(" -> [dataRecived] "+msg);
}
```

And place this functions to HashMap for each type identifier.
Now you can process all messages with vary size unified.